# What is the difference when using dismissViewController?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

A:ChildViewController:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

B: ParentViewController:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

What is the difference between A and B?

Answer (score -2):

`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is a deprecated API, which was exposed by Apple before the shift to more block-based API. In difference to Vizlix, I will say that `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` should never be used. It is no longer maintained at Apple, or at least not properly, as there are some peculiar side effects to using it, which go away when using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. The old API should only be used in specific code paths which only target older iOS versions. The side-effects I speak of are there from at least iOS6.

On top of that, the block-based API gives functionality that is just not possible with the old-style API (functionality, that is direly missing from push;pop API, for instance). Imagine needing to create a chain of view controller events. Without knowing when the animation has finished, you have a large chance of hitting a bug due to performing an animation while another is in progress. with the block-based API, you can chain such events much easily.

Comment: First Match your answer with  what jxdwinter is asking!! He is not asking what is deprecated and what old API is maintaining as a structure of code. He has just asked the difference? Even every body knows [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] is deprecated. lolz;-)